# Removing Apache per user directories

Tags: apache-2.2, localhost, user-permissions

I am trying to access my localhost but I am getting  a "Not Found" error. What I am trying to do is get to my Sites directory (/User/[username]/Sites).

Right now I have the following commented:

```
# Real-time info on requests and configuration
# Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-info.conf
```

I've also got my permissions correct:

```
User [username]
Group staff
```

Any info would be great. Also if someone could give me the correct naming of this technique - that would be helpful. Instead of just calling it "Removing Apache per user directories."

Thank You!

Comment: Your logs say...?

Comment: Sorry - I actually should have checked that out and included it. But I actually forgot to add locahost as a virtual host. My bad!

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind everyone. What I really needed to do was add the virtual host within my vhost.conf file as so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/[username]/Sites"
    ServerName locahost
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localhost-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localhost-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I apologize for the confusion.